# html createLinearGradient not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to create a curve with a gradient that follows it [tangentially](https://i.imgur.com/DLHwVs6.png). Since its not possible to do that by default, i've taken to splitting the curve into a series of quadrilaterals and applying a gradient to each one. However, it seems that the gradient is not going in the correct direction. I've made the quadrilaterals larger to make it easier to see [here](https://i.imgur.com/TAhiTbF.png). The black lines represent the `x0, y0` and `x1, y1` inputs to `ctx.createLinearGradient()` for each shape.

So i calculate the `x` and `y` for points `1, 2, 3, 4` (which go in clockwise direction around the shape starting from the top left), and then calculate the gradient direction line from the middle of the top of the shape to the middle of the bottom.

```js
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
ctx.lineTo(x3, y3);
ctx.lineTo(x4, y4);

const grd_x1 = (x1 + x2) / 2;
const grd_y1 = (y1 + y2) / 2;
const grd_x2 = (x3 + x4) / 2;
const grd_y2 = (y3 + y4) / 2;

const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(
    grd_x1,
    grd_y1,
    grd_x2,
    grd_y2
);
gradient.addColorStop(0, "#3acbfcc3");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "#ffffff00");
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fill();
```

Hence i would expect the gradient would follow the direction of the black lines like [this](https://i.imgur.com/91aCdVD.png). However, in the shapes it is clear that the gradient is not going in that direction like [this](https://i.imgur.com/DZ0MBnX.png). I expect that the top two corner have the same colour (blue) and the bottom two corners have the same colour (white). Am i interpreting the inputs to the function wrong? The diagram at the top of [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createLinearGradient) makes me think it should work.

Comment: What parameters are you passing to that function? Your code makes sense: https://jsfiddle.net/9xpe8ro2/1

Comment: @Kaiido which function are you referring to?

Comment: What are the values of `x1`, `y1` etc. that you are using? wan you provide a complete and reproducible example?

Comment: @Kaiido im actually doing this in svelte, so you can see it here: https://svelte.dev/repl/5490c7f2e2a64b61a3696fe4deabeec5?version=3.59.1

The gist of it is it redraws the curve every 10 ms triggered by the setinterval(). The page tracks the amount of time elapsed since the page has been opened, and shifts the curve along a bit based on the time elapsed. So x1-x4 is coming from stepping along the screen, and y1-y4 is coming from the wave curve function. The 4 points are translated and rotated manually from the rotate() and translate() functions.

Comment: Actually i think i might have worked out why its not looking correct, the gradient wont follow parallel to the shape because the gradient is perpendicular to the line, which is not perpendicular to the length of my shapes. The line i should be giving to createLinearGradient should be perpendicualr to the top/bottom of the shape, and look like the red arrow in this image: https://i.imgur.com/PsClcjw.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However paradoxical it may seem at first glance, but in your case **gradients shouldn't be rendered the way how you intuitively think you want them to be oriented**.

As can be seen [from the article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createLinearGradient) you already linked to:

[image]

Gradients are rendered parallel to the specified vector. Which means that the **color is constant along any perpendicular to that vector**.

---

Yet your vectors are **not orthogonal** to the frontal segments of the wave, so you end up with gradients which are:

- Changing their colors along frontal segments, where color is expected to be constant.
- Misaligned with each other, while they should be visually continuous.

[image]
[image]

---

In order to align gradients properly, you have to make them orthogonal to their corresponding frontal segments, and in the same time ensure that colors propagate uniformly along *common desired gradient vectors*.

How both requirements are met, can be visualized using a parallelogram created from the frontal segment and desired gradient vector attached to it (which is how you are already constructing your quadrilaterals). Now you only have to connect the *line of the frontal side* with the *line of the opposite side*, by drawing a perpendicular.

**This perpendicular is the solution you are looking for.**

[image]

The starting point can lie anywhere on the frontal segment, since by definition (and by design) it will be orthogonal to the gradient. The ending point can be found by solving linear algebra equations.

---

I wanted to practice anyway, so here's the demo!

```js
function renderWaveSegment ({ ctx, x1, y1, x2, y2, xGradient, yGradient, color1, color2 }) {

    // Linear algebra to calc proper ending point of the gradient
    let v1x = y2 - y1;
    let v1y = x1 - x2;
    let v3x = x2 - x1;
    let v3y = y2 - y1;
    let t = (v3x * yGradient - v3y * xGradient) / (v1y * v3x - v1x * v3y);
    let xg = x1 + v1x * t;
    let yg = y1 + v1y * t;

    let gradient;
    try {
        // Just in case if there're NaNs or Infinities and createLinearGradient decides to throw,
        // don't let it ruin the party!
        gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(x1, y1, xg, yg);
    }
    catch (e) { return; }
    gradient.addColorStop(0, color1);
    gradient.addColorStop(1, color2);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
    ctx.lineTo(x2 + xGradient, y2 + yGradient);
    ctx.lineTo(x1 + xGradient, y1 + yGradient);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    ctx.fill();
}

function renderWave ({ ctx, xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd, step, phase, period, amplitude, xGradient, yGradient, color1, color2 }) {

    let length = Math.hypot(xEnd - xStart, yEnd - yStart);
    let xUnit = (xEnd - xStart) / length;
    let yUnit = (yEnd - yStart) / length;
    let xNormal = -yUnit * amplitude;
    let yNormal =  xUnit * amplitude;
    period /= Math.PI * 2;

    function waveFrontAt (pos) {
        let sin = Math.sin(phase + pos / period);
        return [
            xStart + pos * xUnit + sin * xNormal,
            yStart + pos * yUnit + sin * yNormal
        ];
    }

    // Reduce aliasing artifacts between segments by slightly overlapping them
    let overlap = 0.0525;

    for (var pos = 0; pos < length - step; pos += step) {
        let [x1, y1] = waveFrontAt(pos - overlap);
        let [x2, y2] = waveFrontAt(pos + step + overlap);
        renderWaveSegment({ ctx, x1, y1, x2, y2, xGradient, yGradient, color1, color2 });
    }

    let [x1, y1] = waveFrontAt(pos - overlap);
    let [x2, y2] = waveFrontAt(length + overlap);
    renderWaveSegment({ ctx, x1, y1, x2, y2, xGradient, yGradient, color1, color2 });
}

let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function render () {

    let time = Date.now() / 1000;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    renderWave({
        ctx,

        // Starting point of the wave
        xStart: -50,
        yStart: canvas.height * (Math.sin(time * 1.77) * 0.3 + 0.4),

        // Ending point of the wave
        xEnd: canvas.width + 50,
        yEnd: canvas.height * (Math.sin(time * 1.22) * 0.3 + 0.4),

        // Width of segment in pixels (along the baseline)
        step: 5,

        // Sine function (phase in radians, period and amplitude in pixels)
        phase: time * 10,
        period: Math.sin(time * 0.77) * 30 + 70,
        amplitude: 10,

        // Desired gradient vector and colors
        xGradient: Math.sin(time * 2.11) * 40,
        yGradient: Math.sin(time * 3.33) * 35 + 85,
        color1: '#3acbfcc3',
        color2: '#ffffff00'
    });
    window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

render();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="175"></canvas>
```

Also note that iteratively filling paths with `CanvasRenderingContext2D` always leaves gaps between adjacent shapes, which otherwise are expected to be rendered seamlessly. This is an unfortunate "feature" of antialiased rendering when performed in several steps on top of each other rather than drawing everything at once (but canvas is leaving us with no choice anyway). I tried to minimize these artifacts by slightly overlapping quadrilaterals, so I hope they are not so noticeable and annoying now.

Of course, there's [WebGL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API) at everyone's service, which allows to make quality and performant shaders, provided that one is ready to take the time to learn it.

Comment: yeah this was what the issue turned out to be, as i mentioned in discussion under the OP. thanks for writing it up properly though. Regarding the gaps between the adjacent shapes, i found when i made the segments 10px wide and gave them some alpha, the visible lines disappeared.

Comment: https://svelte.dev/repl/5490c7f2e2a64b61a3696fe4deabeec5?version=3.59.1 you can see my final version here.

Comment: @LolLol Nice effect! Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score -3):

This doesn't work with gradients...

```
ctx.fill();
```

So replace it with this...

```
ctx.fillRect(0,0,C.width,C.height);
```

Or specify some other region... but it's gotta be a region.

**NB**: Change "C" with your canvas identifier.

---

This test is for **somethinghere**...

JS:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 200, 0);

gradient.addColorStop(0, "green");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "pink");

ctx.fillStyle = gradient;

ctx.fill();  // <-- here's your idea

//ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 200, 100); // <-- here's mine
```

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Which one works?

Comment: This is false, it does work with `fill()` - if it only worked with `fillRect` it would be rather useless. There must be another issue in the OP's code, but this is not it.

Comment: Negative... run a test.

Comment: Negative, I did. You can use a gradient on any path. Also, you have no path. The point isn’t to discourage use of fill, just to remind you need to fill something.

Comment: You are better of pointing out there should be a path to fill, rather than discouraging using fill() by suggesting what you should do is use fillRect()

Comment: As you can see from my discussion under the OP, it clearly does work with fill(), like at https://svelte.dev/repl/5490c7f2e2a64b61a3696fe4deabeec5?version=3.59.1
The issue turned out to be that a gradient line going along the length of a parallelogram  isnt perpendicular to its ends, so i was getting a different gradient to what i expected.